# Unable to read an audio CD in Debian 9.2

Tags: debian, audio-cd, abcde

I'm running a debian 9.2 machine with a Plextor PX-716A DVD-Drive as `/dev/sr0`. I would like to rip a music CD to MP3 using `abcde`. When I try to to launch `abcde` :

```
$ abcde -V -d /dev/sr0
CDDB method 0: cddb
Executing customizable pre-read function... done.
Getting CD track info... [WARNING] something went wrong while querying the CD... Maybe a DATA CD?
[WARNING] Error trying to calculate disc ids without lead-out information.
```

After a few investigations, I tried `cdparanoia`, without success :

```
$ cdparanoia -vsQ
cdparanoia III release 10.2 (September 11, 2008)

Using cdda library version: 10.2
Using paranoia library version: 10.2
Checking /dev/cdrom for cdrom...
    Testing /dev/cdrom for SCSI/MMC interface
        SG_IO device: /dev/sr0

CDROM model sensed sensed: PLEXTOR DVDR   PX-716A 1.08 

Checking for SCSI emulation...
    Drive is ATAPI (using SG_IO host adaptor emulation)

Checking for MMC style command set...
    Drive is MMC style
004: Unable to read table of contents header

Unable to open disc.  Is there an audio CD in the drive?
```

The I did the same with `cd-discid` :

```
$ cd-discid 
cd-discid: /dev/cdrom: CDROMREADTOCHDR: Input/output error
```

I also think about a permissions problem so I verified :

```
$ ls -al /dev/sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root cdrom 11, 0 Nov 21 22:32 /dev/sr0
```

and the user that I use is in the group `cdrom`.

To be sure that my drive is working I put a DVD inside it. I can mount it and access the content, so the DVD drive is not broken. I tried the CD on a CD player it works fine, I also tried another music CD and I've got the same result.

Finally I think that my DVD drive is unable to read the music CD, so I check with `cd-info` :

```
$ cd-info /dev/sr0
cd-info version 0.83 i686-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (c) 2003, 2004, 2005, 2007, 2008, 2011 R. Bernstein
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CD location   : /dev/sr0
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : PLEXTOR 
Model                       : DVDR   PX-716A  
Revision                    : 1.08
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : No
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: No information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: Input/output error

cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up.
```

As you can read, this drive is able to read music. In the end, I tried to install `vlc`and `mplayer` but none succeed in reading the CD. I'm now lost and far to accomplish a rip !

I would like your suggestions on this problem. Any ideas what to check next ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying with another DVD Drive I was able to rip using `abcde`. So I can answer my own question and confirm the suggestion of Stephen, my first drive is broken.

I lost time, but I learned a few things. Hope my investigation described above helps someone.